# How to call this framing problem in Japanese?

Tags: word-requests

How to call a picture where due to a camera handling error or inopportune subject move, the subject is not at the intended place (for instance center of the picture), but instead at the edge of the picture, or even out of the picture.

For instance, I take a picture of someone but the camera slips in my hand and the resulting picture has the head of the person cut off.

In French it is called "erreur de [cadrage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadrage_photographique)".

If there is no such word, how to call the action of rotating the camera to place the subject at the intended place in the picture?

I would say "フレーミング失敗" but I guess it does not sound natural.

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong but I think this question is asking for translation without an attempt to translate and thus is off-topic.

Comment: @Szymon: Fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「フレーミングミス」?

In normal conversation you'd say 「(足が)切れてる。」or「(頭が)切れちゃった」.

Comment: 見切れる can be taken into account, too.

Comment: @user4092 「見切れる」は初めて聞きます。写真の専門用語でしょうか？

Comment: もしかすると専門用語・業界用語のたぐいかもしれません。自分自身どこで聞き知ったかわかりません。It might be a kind of jargon. I'm not sure myself where I caught it.